# PHP CSV Import Script

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to import a CSV file and upload it to my database. First I tested this with some dummy data that did not contain special characters. But now that I have the final CSV it doesn't seem to read the columns properly. I have seen many answers to others having similar problems but weren't able to fix my problem with it.

What I want to achieve: one array for each row of the CSV file, with each column as an array index. I can't seem to figure this out :/ Thanks for your help!

This is a screenshot of the first 5 rows of the CSV file:

[image: screenshot of the first 5 rows of the CSV file]

Code:

```
// csv settings
$filename = 'files/games3.csv';
$fp = fopen($filename, "r");
// insert for each row of csv file
$i=0;
while (($row = fgetcsv($fp)) != FALSE)
{
    // first 5 rows only (just for testing)
    if ($i <= 5){
        //$arrIm = implode(";", $row);
        //$arrEx = explode(";", $arrIm);
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($row);
        echo '</pre>';
        $i++;
    }
    else{
        die('done');
    }
}
fclose($fp);
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: have you looked at your CSV-file with a text editor and check if it's valid?

Comment: Hi @FranzGleichmann . Yes, I have opened it in my text editor. This doesn't give me any errors...

Comment: that may be, but is the content valid CSV? i have experiences with certain spreadsheet programs that suck at generating CSV

Comment: Your last column with all the linebreaks needs to be enclosed in quotes `"`.  Only way I know to get it to work.  And `fgetcsv()` will need `;` as the separator.

Comment: I have just ran a test on the script on [link](http://csvlint.io/) and this test outputs the file has 3811 errors...

Comment: Probably because it's not a CSV (comma separated).  It is semi-colon separated. And all the newlines.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your product_description_long has carriage return/line feed characters.

This will make it easy to parse your data: https://github.com/synappnz/php-csv

```
include "csv.php";
$csv = new csv(file_get_contents("filename.csv"));
$rows = $csv->rows();
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
  // do something with $row
}
```